# Angular ag-Grid: how to refresh param value in custom cell renderer that is passed from the parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have my custom cell renderer for the editing menu:

[image]

To the renderer component I'm passing `isEditing` value, because when user click on Edit, then

```
agInit(params: ICellRendererParams) {
 this.params = params;
 this.data = params.data;
 this.isEditing = this.params.isEditing;
}
```

And in template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isEditing">
HERE IS MENU ICON VIEW
</ng-container>
<div *ngIf="isEditing" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" (click)="onSave()">{{'shared.save' | translate}} 
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-1" (click)="onCancel()">{{'shared.cancel' | translate}}</button>
</div>
```

In my parent component where is the grid I have my column definition:

```
  headerName: '',
  cellRendererFramework: EditRendererComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {
    isEditing: this.isEditing
  }
```

The problem is I want to manage `isEditing` flag from the parent level. But when I start row edition onClick then `(rowEditingStarted)` is triggered and I'm changing the flag:

```
{
this.isEditing = true;
this.gridApi.refreshCells({force: true});
}
```

As you can see, I tried to use `refreshingCells` method from gridApi but it doesn't help me. Maybe on of you have some idea to handle this?

Comment: could u reproduce this issue on plunk or stackblitz so that we can try and provide the solution easily?

Answer (score 1):

make cell params available via function like this:

```
  cellRendererParams: {
    isEditing: () => this.isEditing
  }
```

and use it as a function:

```html
 <div *ngIf="isEditing()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a similar method to what you implemented but could not get it to work. The value was not changing.
Instead...
I used a service which I subscribe to in the custom renderer. In the parent component I have a button which toggles the "isEditing" variable and updates the value in the observable.

> Parent Component

```
this._TableRendererService.updateIsEdit(this.isEdit);
```

> Custom Renderer

```
  agInit(params: any) {
    this.params = params;
    this._TableRendererService.currentIsEdit.subscribe(isEdit => this.isEdit = isEdit);
  }
```